# If the $\det(A)=0$ why does the matrix $A$ have an eigenvector?

Tags: linear-algebra, eigenvalues-eigenvectors

1. If the $\det(A)=0$ why does the matrix $A$ have an eigenvector?
2. Explain why there is a basis $B$ in $R^n$ so that the matrix $[A]_B$ has the zero vector as its first column

I know that if the $\det(A)=0$ of a matrix is zero then it is singular and thus not invertible. That in turn means that it doesn't have one solution. Why does that mean that it has an eigenvector?

As for the second I have no idea.

Comment: every matrix has a eigen value and thus eigen vector ( can be complex though )

Answer (score 3):

If $A$ is not invertible, then necessarily there exists a nonzero $v$ such that $Av=0$. This means that $0$ is an eigenvalue of $A$.

For part 2, let $v$ be the first element in your basis. Then the first column of $[A]_B$ is $Av$, which is the zero vector.

Comment: Why is the first column of $[A]_B$ equal to $Av$?

Comment: If $B=(v_1, v_2, \ldots, v_n)$, then by definition the columns in $[A]_B$ are $Av_1, Av_2, \ldots, Av_n$.

Comment: I thought it was like this: $[A]_B = B^-1*A * B$

Comment: Where can I read about what you stated? I tried googling but nothing.

Answer (score 1):

There exists $x\not= 0$ satisfying  $Ax = 0$. Thus $Ax = 0x$ and $x$ is an eigenvector.

Answer (score 1):

$det\  A = 0$ means $0$ is an eigenvalue. that is there is at least one nonzero vector
$x$ such that $Ax = 0.$ the number of such linearly independent vectors is called the dimension of the null space $ker A.$ if you set up a basis $B$ with the first vector $x$ we found earlier, then the at least the first column of the matrix with respect to the basis $B$ has a zero column.

Comment: Thank you for your answer! One more question: Is the basis $B$ made of eigenvectors?

Comment: Not necessarily. $\det A=0$ only implies that 0 is an eigenvalue, not that $A$ is diagonalizable (i.e. has a basis of eigenvectors). For example, take $A=\begin{pmatrix}1&0\\0&0 \end{pmatrix}$. Then all eigenvectors are of the form $(0,c),c\in\mathbb R$, so we cannot find two linearly independent eigenvectors to form a basis.

Comment: If $B=(v1,v2,…,vn)$, then by definition the columns in $[A]_B$ are $Av1,Av2,…,Avn$ is the comment from Math1000. Any idea where I can find more info about this. I tried googling but didn't find anything.

Comment: you can see read about this linear algebra text e.g. strang's introduction to linear algebra. look for change of basis formula.

Answer (score 1):

The matrix $A$ has an eigenvector for the value $\lambda$ (which is then an eigenvalue) if and only if $\det(A-\lambda I)=0$. This holds in particular for $\lambda=0$, which is the case you are asking about.